# PHP Namespace 5.3 and WordPress Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces

I am using namespaces.

I try to create a WordPress widget (http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)

With namespaces the following gives an error because the arguments can not be passed (and without namespaces it obviously works like usual)

```
 namespace a\b\c;
 class whatever extends \WP_Widget {
   function whatever() {
     parent::WP_Widget('name1', 'name2');
   }
 // .. other functions left out
 }
 add_action('widgets_init',
 create_function('', 'return register_widget("a\b\c\whatever");'));
```

uhm... what is the correct syntax for 'parent::WP_Widget' using namespaces?

*(the COMPLETE error message is:*

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wp2\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 324 and defined in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wp2\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 93
```

*)*

*And the debugger shows nothing has been passed:*

```
Variables in local scope (#14)
$control_options = Undefined
$id_base = boolean false 
$name = Undefined
$widget_options =  Undefined
```

*(only the $name is required)*

Comment: Post exact error message here. From looking at the code it does not look like there is anything wrong. Also why do you use parent and not just $this->WP_Widget?
And lastly, is WP_Widget a constructor of the WP_Widget class? Why does the function have the same name as the class? If its a constructor, then better use __construct()

Comment: no: there is, the widget factory is part of WordPress since 2.8 : if you click in Eclipse on WP_Widget you get the definition it is in ... http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/widgets it SHOULD be overwritten and not by _construct, see source code (cant help it did not write it)

Comment: @dmitri: both parent::WP_Widget and $this->WP_Widget deliver the same error, both variant are used around the web. WP_Widget is the function that should be overwritten according to the CODEX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me your problem is not in the namespaces, the following code works like a charm:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class Bar {
    function __construct( $foo ) {
        echo "$foo\n";
    }
}

namespace Foo\Bar;

class Foo extends \Foo\Bar {
    function __construct( ) {
        parent::__construct( "This should work." );
    }
}

$foo = new \Foo\Bar\Foo( );
```

If you get an error message, it might be helpful to state what it says.

Comment: @berry-langerak: Good to know its not my syntax GRIN. Then... what is it? The parent class is default: core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/widgets

Comment: It seems Wordpress has a proxy method for the old PHP 4 type constructors (yugh). You might want to consider using parent::__construct( ) instead. Also, when calling __construct( ), be sure to call it with *at least* two parameters.

Comment: Why would you mark an answer as correct when its not even a direct answer to your question, if the comments lead to the resolving of the error, please update your post.

Comment: @RobertPitt the code in the answer is the correct code: i needed the function _construct and then in there the parent::_construct as in the answer as opposed to the documentation code here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Answer (score 22):

Looking at the documentation [located here](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Widgets/WP_Widget.html) it seems that only the name is required but the way PHP works your have to have the pre variables defined as well.

You have two ways of creating the class:

- A:

  - `WP_Widget __construct ([string $id_base = false], string $name, [array $widget_options = array()], [array $control_options = array()])`
- B:

  - `WP_Widget WP_Widget ([ $id_base = false],  $name, [ $widget_options = array()], [ $control_options = array()])`

By preference you should always use the `__construct` method to initialize your object, i would rewrite you code like so:

```
namespace a\b\c;

class whatever extends \WP_Widget
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('name1', 'name2');
    }

    /*
         * Other methods!
    */
}
```

The `WP_Widget::WP_Widget(..)` method is for PHP4 only, and should not be used in PHP 5 or higher.

Now it seems that your using PHP 5.3 as your using name spaces so you can do the following:

```
add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    return register_widget(new a\b\c\whatever);
});
```

Comment: the function __construct did the trick thanks, the answer was just a minute later than berry so i marked berry as the answer.

Comment: the regiser_widget addition does not work with the \a\b\c\ in it since it is in the namespace scope. If I remove the namespace part it gives "Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp2\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 324" so... i use the code in the question for now and will check later on how to do this. thanks.

Comment: Just encapsulate the `a\b\c\whatever` within a string and remove the new keyword, it may be down to the way Wordpress uses the value.

Comment: yes that works: add_action('widgets_init',function(){
return register_widget('a\b\c\whatever');
}); thanks

Comment: There is a problem with passing false for $id_base (as of WordPress 3.3.1).  In wp-admin/includes/widgets.php, $id_base is used as part of a regular expression (line 118), and the backslashes from the namespace will cause problems.  I suggest changing your examples to always give an $id_base explicitl, and note it should not contain regular expression meta-characters.  In particular, it should not contain dots, which though they may not cause problems as RE meta-characters, will cause problems when converted to underscores in form processing.

Answer (score 3):

You want to call a parent method? Simply use `parent::MethodName();`

If you want to call the parent constructor, use `parent::__construct()` - if your constructor is named like the class, rename it to `__construct` which is the preferred name for a constructor for years...

Comment: thanks, i must be missing something im already using parent::WP_Widget() already but im probably overlooking something?

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me:

```
add_action('widgets_init', function() {                 
    register_widget('\a\b\c\whatever');
});
```

Comment: register_widget [accepts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_widget/#parameters) both class name and instance. If you need to use a class name, use `\a\b\c\whatever::class` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use PHP's native `get_class` method, which will return any class instantiation's name as a string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

`register_widget(get_class(new \UCI\Wordpress\Widget\Footer()));`

Answer (score -1):

I don't use Wordpress, but from looking at this it looks like its due to a very bad design of Wordpress. They seem to use static function WP_Widget which serves as a factory but shares the same name as class name. They should have called it *factory* if it really is just a factory.

Also, from what you posted in your comment, maybe you need to create a static function WP_Widget() in your subclass and then don't even call the parent. If the script really wants you to override the WP_Widget then this is what you should do.

But again, I have never used Wordpress, it's hard to tell without looking at the script.

You should post the exact error code here.

Comment: I have posted the complete exact error code, i can add the stack trace?